# How Avoid Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new about node js and I'm tring to write an Hello Word. This is the code:

```
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

When I start node, I call the file in this way and I obtain Unexpected Identifier Exception:

http://it.tinypic.com/r/n3uo45/8

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Pic is not working for me.  Also, please put the needed information in the post directly as external links may change.

Comment: you need to start it with `node HelloWorld.js` I haven't any problem doing that.

Comment: @michelem I'm tring to call node HelloWord.js but it is the same think. Do you know if I must collocate the node js exe in a particolar folder?

Comment: No, sorry never installed it on Windows.

Comment: You are calling the `node script` from inside node REPL. Run the command directly from cmd.